# 'news_from_date' in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using the Magento API to make a product "New" with the following

```
'news_from_date' => date("d/m/Y h:i:s");
```

using `catalog_product.update`

This works perfectly fine and shows the item as "New"

However, I am now trying to make an item previously marked as "New" not to be new. I thought I could do this again with catalog_product.update and just making

```
'news_from_date' => null;
```

But this only sets the date to - 30/11/1999 which obviously keeps the item as "New" Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**

I have also tried the following with no joy -

```
'news_from_date' => "00/00/00 00:00:00";
```

Thanks

Comment: could you describe how you did this exactly? I'm trying to update a product with the news_from_date value added but I get an error that this parameter isn't recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Proper SQL DateTime format

Magento SQL stores dates in this format:

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

---

**So instead of:**

`'news_from_date' => "00/00/00 00:00:00";`

`'news_from_date' => date("d/m/Y h:i:s");`

**Use:**

`'news_from_date' => "0000-00-00 00:00:00";`

`'news_from_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the attribute `news_to_date` to any of the previous date.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the product date like that :

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($PRD_ID);
$_product->setData('news_from_date', date("d/m/Y h:i:s"));
$_product->setData('news_to_date', date("d/m/Y h:i:s", strtotime('+1 week')));
```

Comment: Why is this voted down? It seems to not work, but why?

Comment: $_product->setData('news_from_date', date("Y-m-d h:i:s"));
$_product->setData('news_to_date', date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+1 week")));